Freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException error when trying to validate user input Apache FreeMarker
There is such ftlh file with registration form:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Rental Property</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>User Registration</h2>
<form action="/registration" method="POST">

    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="${userForm.name!}" required>
    <#if errors?? && errors?has_content && errors.hasFieldErrors("name")>
        <div style="color:red;">${errors.getFieldError('name').defaultMessage}</div>
    </#if>

    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="${userForm.lastName!}" required>
    <#if errors?? && errors?has_content && errors.hasFieldErrors("lastName")>
        <div style="color:red;">${errors.getFieldError("lastName").defaultMessage}</div>
    </#if>

    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="${userForm.email!}" required>
    <#if errors?? && errors?has_content && errors.hasFieldErrors("email")>
        <div style="color:red;">${errors.getFieldError("email").defaultMessage}</div>
    </#if>

    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" value="${userForm.phone!}">
    <#if errors?? && errors?has_content && errors.hasFieldErrors("phone")>
        <div style="color:red;">${errors.getFieldError("phone").defaultMessage}</div>
    </#if>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
    <#if errors?? && errors?has_content && errors.hasFieldErrors("password")>
        <div style="color:red;">${errors.getFieldError("password").defaultMessage}</div>
    </#if>

    <label for="replayPassword">Repeat Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="replayPassword" name="replayPassword" required>
    <#if errors?? && errors?has_content && errors.hasFieldErrors("replayPassword")>
        <div style="color:red;">${errors.getFieldError("replayPassword").defaultMessage}</div>
    </#if>

    <label for="birthday">Date of Birth:</label>
    <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
    <#--    <#if errors?has_content && errors.hasFieldErrors("birthday")>-->
    <#--        <div style="color:red;">${errors.getFieldError("birthday").defaultMessage}</div>-->
    <#--    </#if>-->

    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

There is such a method of post request processing:
@PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserForm userForm,
                               BindingResult result, Model model)
    {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, result);
        model.addAttribute("errors", result);
        if (result.hasErrors())
            return "registration";
        return "redirect:/";
    }

Above each field of the UserForm.java class are validation annotations from jakarta.validation.constraints and also a custom validator class.
When trying to send data with errors inside this controller method the validation works as it should, all errors are looked for and an error occurs when trying to display incorrect data to the user:
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> errors.getFieldError('name')  [in template "registration.ftlh" at line 14, column 35]

----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${errors.getFieldError("name").defaul...  [in template "registration.ftlh" at line 14, column 33]
----
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134) ~[freemarker-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.newDescriptionBuilder(UnexpectedTypeException.java:85) ~[freemarker-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]...

I tried changing the error key in the ftlh file to single quotes, changing the validation, sending the entire assembled UserForm object.

Side note: errors?? && errors?has_content can be simplified to errors?has_content, as ?has_content checks for null as well.

I suspect the problem is that you haven't enabled exposing Java 8 default methods. It's needed as FreeMarker is based upon java.beans.Introspector (the official JavaBeans introspector) which oddly ignores them. So, as the version history says for 2.3.26 (https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/versions_2_3_26.html):

Added workaround (not enabled by default) to expose Java 8 default methods (and the bean properties they define) to templates, despite that java.beans.Introspector (the official JavaBeans introspector) ignores them, at least as of JRE 1.8.0_66. To enable this workaround, either increase the value of the incompatibleImprovements constructor argument of DefaultObjectWrapper or BeansWrapper the used to 2.3.26, or set its treatDefaultMethodsAsBeanMembers setting to true. Note that if you leave the object_wrapper setting of the Configuration on its default, it's enough to increase the incompatibleImprovements setting of the Configuration to 2.3.26, as that's inherited by the default object_wrapper.

My recommendation is increasing the incompatibleImprovements setting of the Configuration. There are several surprising issues that are emulated for 100% backward compatibility otherwise. There's the page about how to set it:
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_incompatible_improvements.html#pgui_config_incompatible_improvements_how_to_set
